# what is the best way to use server side rendering with react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux-saga, server-side-rendering, react-router-dom

I have tried dozens of server side rendering with reactjs / nodejs, but nothing is working perfectly with me.

Is there any way to use server side rendering and code / style splitting with react js / redux saga / react router dom / node ?

Answer (score 3):

### Framework

As of today, the easiest way to implement SSR with React, in my opinion, is to use [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/).

You get isomorphic/universal rendering out of the box, along with other built-in features including code-splitting and pre-fetching.

Static routing is also included. If you need dynamic routing, it's relatively easy to roll your own, or you can use [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes).

### Boilerplate

If you're looking for more of a customized solution, [react-cool-starter](https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter) is a solid boilerplate.

Comment: I have tried next.js, but i think it is in the early stage.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a specific feature you need that is not yet available in Next.js? I've built multiple production apps on the framework without any limitations.

Comment: I've also updated my answer with a solid boilerplate that I've used in the past.

Comment: I have faced problem in jwt auth with next.js before, and nested routes, i will try your option, and next.js again.

Answer (score 0):

you may check my starter (https://github.com/gzoreslav/react-redux-saga-universal-application). I've wrote them using official recommendations from Redux and React-Router v4

It uses: react, react-router, redux, redux-saga

Hope it helps

Comment: Great boilerplate, but i didn't see if there code / style splitting, Thank you